# Why is directly manipulating the Rails form params hash considered code smell?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a Rails form with a parent model and nested attributes for potentially multiple children of another model.

The child model has an attribute which is manipulated in logic as an array, but is serialized to a YAML string using the Rails built-in serialize method.

Within the form, I display each individual member of the array so that the user can selectively delete members.

The problem happens when the user destroys all members. The form will not pass any value for the param to the Rails controller and when the UPDATE action is called, it ignores the attribute since there is no key for it in the forms params hash. This is of course a known problem with things like checkboxes, so Rails automatically puts 2 checkbox HTML elements for each checkbox, one hidden that only processes if the checkbox is checked off.

I'm not dealing with checkboxes here but rather hidden input text fields.

The solution I've implemented is to manipulate the params hash directly in the UPDATE action of the controller, like this:

```
params[:series][:time_slots_attributes].each { |k,v| v[:exdates] ||= [] }
```

Is this considered code smell?

Should I instead add an extra hidden field that is disabled and only gets enabled when the user removes the last member? This solution works as well, but it seems clunky to me.

Comment: @Deefour, that doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that when the params hash is processed by the UPDATE action, an empty array needs to be written into the DB. I guess I could inspect the params value to see if the key is present and if it isn't I could separately update that attribute for each child as appropriate.

Comment: Something like this: `params[:series][:time_slots_attributes].each_with_index do |attribs,idx|
      @series.time_slots[idx].update_attribute(:exdates, []) unless attribs[1].has_key?(:exdates)
    end`

Comment: you asked if it was code smell; that is the one and only thing I was responding to.

Comment: @Deefour, okay fair enough...thanks. What I'm looking for is a deeper explanation of why manipulating the params hash is a bad practice. If I get a broader idea of all the implications, I can make a better decision as to whether I want to violate a best practice in this one exception.

Comment: That's application logic that should be done in the model (i.e. pass the params hash to a method in the model).

Comment: How about overriding the update_attributes method for the parent model?

Answer (score 1):

This is dealt with in the NestedAttributes module by allowing a "_destroy" parameter to trigger a destroy call for that particular nested attribute:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for.

If you're not using nested attributes (which you probably should be, it's pretty neat in a lot of situations) then yes, you'll have to handroll something yourself, by working out which values *should* have been present and doing something special with those.

Comment: We are using accepts_nested_attributes_for with :allow_destroy => true, but does this only work with checkbox form fields?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused here, but I think the "_destroy" parameter is to destroy the child object, not the nested attribute? I'm not trying to destroy the entire child object. I'm trying to allow a user to persist an array attribute that is either (a) unchanged, (b) changed but still has values, or (c) no longer has values. (a) and (b) are not a problem. (c) does not work when all input tags for a given attribute are disabled, the attribute never appears in the params hash at all and so no changes are made to the attribute.

Comment: I should add that the fact that my example uses parent and child models is irrelevant. This same issue comes up with a simple single model form. My example was chosen from a real current problem which incidentally was in a form using nested attributes, but again is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Okay, so basically I shouldn't be serializing this data into a string because it prevents me from treating each array element as a child object and thereby I could destroy each element individually when processing the form using accepts_nested_attributes_for, :allow_destroy => true ?

Answer (score 0):

This is far from an exhaustive answer...but after thinking about this problem, one issue I can see is that if future forms are built that leverage the same UPDATE action, unexpected behavior will occur, which violates the principle of least surprise. If at a later time a second form is built which does not expect to change values for the exdates attribute (since it does not pass them), the UPDATE action will write an empty array into the attribute anyway.

I've decided to solve this issue by adding a single hidden form field with a true boolean value and later to check for this value before setting all time slot exdates to an empty array. This way, if a future developer creates a new form that leverages the UPDATE action of the series controller, they won't get the unexpected behavior of their exdates being set to empty arrays. If they want to process exdates in their form, they need to have the same hidden form field with a true value. This seemed like a simpler solution then adding a class and table for exdates, migration, and the AR associations and adding another layer of nested attributes so that I'd have not only a parent and children attributes, put a parent, children and grandchildren. This solution is a bit like the Rails hack for dealing with checkboxes with a second hidden checkbox field in the form.